Conditional format if consective cells in a column contain certain text
I'd like to do conditional formatting on column A if consecutive cells in the column contain the text "Grade". In the picture below, only A6 should be highlighted.I tried this
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET(A5,-1,0))),ISBLANK(A5)

but it only highlights after a cell that isn't blank. One caveat is that all the cells have a formula to determine if there is a Grade or not, so they will not really be blank.


Use a rule based on the formula =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Grade",A1)*SEARCH("Grade",A2)), applying it to cells A2:A11.


You can check for the length of the cell instead of ISBLANK:
=IF(AND(LEN(A2)>0,LEN(A1)>0),TRUE,FALSE)

Or when used for conditional formatting:
=AND(LEN(A2)>0,LEN(A1)>0)


Could you try this (F6 being the first cell for range for condition in this example): =COUNTIF(OFFSET(F6,-1,0,2),"Grade*")=2

